# Правка вёрстки. Криво отображается таблица

Tags: html, css

Помогите поправить таблицу. Не могу выровнять 1px. https://skoro-v-roddom.ru/cart_items [image: скрин]

Comment: хочу подметить (это не касается вашего вопроса, но касается сайта) из за того что количество контента в блоках разное -  кнопки "В корзину" не на одной линии находятся.

Comment: это на  insales ?

Comment: Главная » Одежда для мамы » Большие размеры » Белье больших размеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выйдите из редактора сайта и проверьте еще раз.
При обычном просмотре все ровно, да и ячейки по синтаксису по идее не должны менять так высоту
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]